# Client unsubscribed from Channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Is it possible to return the unsubscribed channel 'name' to the unsubscribed method?

When a user unsubscribes from a channel (due to disconnect or navigate away), I need to make sure the client flags are set to a null state.  I've created a cleanup method, but I'm unable to find out which channel the cleanup message should be sent to.. since I'm unable to get which channel the unsubscribed method was called from.

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def follow(data)
    stop_all_streams
    conversation = Conversation.find(data['conversation_id'])
    if conversation.is_participant?(current_user)
      stream_from "conversation:#{data['conversation_id']}"
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed
    clear_typing
  end

  ...

  def clear_typing
    # need way to find out conversation_id of the unsubscribed stream
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation:#{data['conversation_id']}", {id: current_user.id, typing: false}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the class name is the channel name.

From the [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable) docs:

```
# app/channels/appearance_channel.rb
class AppearanceChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    current_user.appear
  end

  def unsubscribed
    current_user.disappear
  end

  def appear(data)
    current_user.appear on: data['appearing_on']
  end

  def away
    current_user.away
  end
end
```

And the client subscribes as follows:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/appearance.coffee
App.cable.subscriptions.create "AppearanceChannel",
  # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  connected: ->
    @install()
    @appear()

  # Called when the WebSocket connection is closed
  disconnected: ->
    @uninstall()

  # Called when the subscription is rejected by the server
  rejected: ->
    @uninstall()

  appear: ->
    # Calls `AppearanceChannel#appear(data)` on the server
    @perform("appear", appearing_on: $("main").data("appearing-on"))

  away: ->
    # Calls `AppearanceChannel#away` on the server
    @perform("away")


  buttonSelector = "[data-behavior~=appear_away]"

  install: ->
    $(document).on "page:change.appearance", =>
      @appear()

    $(document).on "click.appearance", buttonSelector, =>
      @away()
      false

    $(buttonSelector).show()

  uninstall: ->
    $(document).off(".appearance")
    $(buttonSelector).hide()
```

If you look closely, client is subscribing to the channel `AppearanceChannel` which is the name of the class.

Comment: I updated my question because I think maybe I didn't ask quite right.  I think I found the solution too.. was looking into the source for the stop_all_streams method and realized that 'streams' was an available variable in the ChannelClass

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a possible solution, though it would be better if I could grab the exact *unsubscribed stream* if possible:

found this by looking at the stop_all_streams method since it alerted me to the existence of the 'streams' variable.

```
...
  def unsubscribed
    streams.each do |stream|
      ActionCable.server.broadcast stream[0], {id: current_user.id, typing: false}
    end
  end
...
```